# How to update recyclerview inside a fragment(which is inside a viewpager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have an activity which consists of a ViewPager.

The ViewPager consists of multiple fragments.

Each fragment contains a recyclerView with items in it.

Now how do i update the recyclerView?

Eg. The view pager is at 0 position and showing "fragment 1".
On button click, i add an item to the adapter and call notifyItemInserted().

**The PROBLEM is the item gets added to the recylerView of "fragment 2" instead of fragment 1.**

ViewPager adapter:

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("listID", listID);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return lists.get(position).getTitle();
    }
}
```

MyFragment:

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        res = getResources();

        // Inflate a view
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // to allow this fragment to use action bar

        initialize(fragmentView);

        populateRecyclerView();

        // Button click listenmer
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add item to recyclerView
                data.add("Banana");
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateRecyclerView() {
        data = new ArrayList();
        data.add("Apple");
        data.add("Mango");

        // Setup adapter
        mAdapter = new MainListAdapter(getActivity(), MainFragment.this, new ArrayList());

        // Set adapter and populate recyclerView
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If we populate or update our data collection with new data and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter(PagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter instance), adapter’s getItemPosition(Object) is called.

Comment: Hi Amit Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Goblinシ Extending pager adapter class to 'FragmentPagerAdapter' instead of 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' did the trick.

Comment: I did by re-instantiating recyclerview on event and notifyAdapter. Thanks buddy!